# I cant see values from firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Screen Shot 2019-04-01 at 4.45.08 PM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQvgr.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRVb4.png)I want to get the value from firebase that is stored I want to print it into a text label,

```
func fetchData(){
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    guard  let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String , AnyObject> else {return}
        let uid = snapshot.value
        let user = User(uid:uid as! String, dictionary: dictionary)
        self.user = user
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

This is my another code to set the text label

```
func fetchData(){
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    guard  let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String , AnyObject> else {return}
        let uid = snapshot.value
        let user = User(uid:uid as! String, dictionary: dictionary)
        self.userNameLabel.text = user.username
        self.user = user

        print(snapshot)
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

extra code to understand what I am doing

// user info stored

```
  let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let userData = ["userName": userName,
            "userAge ": userAge] as [String? : Any]
         let values = [userID: userData]

        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("users").childByAutoId().setValue(values)



}
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Is there an error message?

Comment: no error just cant see value inside compiler or on the text label I will try to attach one more pic

Comment: Now that I look at it some more though, there's definitely some funny stuff going on in here. For instance, how can `snapshot.value` be both a Dictionary and a String? Why do you assign a value to `ref` but never use it?

Comment: John thanks for the feed back ! i will try to explain as much I can so I have also created a user class a blue print and a dictionary

Comment: or please give a different approach to fetch user value and put it into text label

Comment: Well, your app *should* be crashing when it hits `uid as! String`, because `snapshot.value` is a Dictionary. So since it isn't reaching that point, either your guard statement is failing or the callback isn't being executed at all. I'd suggest setting some breakpoints and stepping through it to make sure all the values are actually what you expect.

Comment: not crashing at all but I have a meet up in Los Angeles  hopefully if they can help or any one here should I post more code ?

Comment: by the way John should I create a label or text field to place my value from firebase inside it I have a  label it say username at the moment

Comment: Like I said, the only way it wouldn't crash is if it isn't reaching that code at all. Possibly Firebase doesn't have the uid you're requesting? That's why I suggest stepping through it and checking the data you're sending and receiving.

Comment: you might be right ok its pretty coco hopefully I sort this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer I wasn't setting the user stored info in the firebase the right way.

```
          let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

          let userData = ["userName": userName,

         "userAge ": userAge] as [String? : Any]



        let ref = Database.database().reference()


       ref.child("users/\(userID ?? "")").setValue(userData)



}
```

//ref.child("users/(userID??"")").setValue(userData) // this was the error

Answer (score 2):

1. I think you should use callbacks to communicate asynchronously with your controller.
2. In your example you get the uid by using "snpashot.value" but you should take the key of your dictionary instead.
3. Here is a similar example :

   ```
   ///Function that returns as callback the user stored in Firebase with a certain id.
   func getUserFor(id: String, callback: @escaping (Bool, User?) -> Void) {

       //Get the user in Firebase "user" collection with the specific id.
       ref.child(Constants.userKey).child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (userSnapshot) in

           guard let userDictionnary = userSnapshot.value as? [String:Any] else { return callback(false, nil) }

           let userId = userSnapshot.key
           let userEmail = userDictionnary[Constants.emailKey] as? String

           let user = User(id: userId, email: userEmail)

           return callback(true, user)
       }) { (error) in
           print(error.localizedDescription)
           return callback(false, nil)
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: josset I think I see your approach it make sense please  help me in keeping a snapshot approach I will add more code of my dictionary and how I stored my user info on firebase

Comment: you mind explaining me this line of code  ref.child("users/\(userID ?? "")").setValue(userData)